# How to create Schema using mongodb(mongoose schema)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have Mobile List with models and rates. I want to create a schema for this. I am new to mongodb and mongoose. Anyone help me out, I have added my requirements.

```
Categories :

nokia

sub Categories :Nokia Lumia 730 -7,000,
                Nokia 225 -5,000,
                Nokia Lumia 1020 -6,000,
                Nokia Lumia 530 -8,0000

Samsung Galaxy A7:
                Samsung Galaxy A7 -10,000,
                Samsung Galaxy A3 -12,000,
                Samsung Galaxy One5 -5,000,
                Samsung Galaxy S5 Neo -6,000


HTC One M9s:

                HTC One M9s -9,000,
                HTC Desire 728G -12,000,
                HTC Desire 526 -4,000,
```

My Expectations:
How can I design schema to solve below condition

1. When I search nokia it should display nokia mobile model with rates.
2. When I search nokia with Nokia Lumia, the result should show matched conditions

This is my full schema

```
var ShopSchema = new Schema({

    Email: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true,

    },
    Storename: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    Type: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    Categories: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    }


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make two different collection for shop and categories

and make schema in nested way

```
var Categories = new Schema({
    name     : String
  , subcategories      : {
    name : String,
    model : String
     }
});


var ShopSchema = new Schema({

    Email: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true,

    },
    Storename: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    Type: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    Categories : [Categories]
});
```

To understand nested schema in mongoose you can visit this [link](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/embedded-documents.html)

I am giving an example to understand more-

Fist of all we have to save store name

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("567a8f004cb6178545bac89c"),
    "Email" : "dineshaws@hotmail.com",
    "Storename" : "Dineshaws",
    "Type" : "XYZ",
    "Categories" : []
}
```

When we'll save single category then it will go into both collection- categories and store

shop collection -

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("567a8f004cb6178545bac89c"),
    "Email" : "dineshaws@hotmail.com",
    "Storename" : "Dineshaws",
    "Type" : "XYZ",
    "Categories" : [
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("567a9be04cb6178545bac89d"),
                "name" : "nokia",
                "subcategories" : []
            }
                   ]
}
```

categories collection -

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("567a9be04cb6178545bac89d"),
    "name" : "nokia",
    "subcategories" : []
}
```

Now if we want to insert subcategory than it will go into both collection as a sub document

categories collection will be look like below-

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("567a9be04cb6178545bac89d"),
    "name" : "nokia",
    "subcategories" : [
            {
                "name" : "Nokia Lumia",
                "model":"Nokia Lumia 730 -7,000"
            }
            ]
}
```

shop collection will be look like this-

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("567a8f004cb6178545bac89c"),
    "Email" : "dineshaws@hotmail.com",
    "Storename" : "Dineshaws",
    "Type" : "XYZ",
    "Categories" : [
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("567a9be04cb6178545bac89d"),
                "name" : "nokia",
                "subcategories" : [{
                            "name" : "Nokia Lumia",
                            "model":"Nokia Lumia 730 -7,000"
                        }
                        ]
            }
                   ]
}
```

You can also change schema according your requirement

Thanks

Comment: can you pls add some example use my given data

Comment: if i want add more data in subcategories

Comment: @komal, It's my pleasure to help you out. Thanks

Comment: i need your help sir @Dineshaws

Comment: @komal yes let me know your problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36712479/how-can-i-check-given-date-is-between-two-dates-in-mongodb @ Dineshaws  pls help me out for this sir