# How can I check given date is between two dates in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date, express

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "asdf976"
  },
  "Categories": [{
    "mainmodels": [{
      "submodels": [{
          "price": "2000",
          "submodelname": "lumia021",

        }, {
          "price": "2000",
          "submodelname": "lumia341",

        }

      ],
      "Status": "Active",
      "modelname": "lumia",
      "fromdate": "15/04/2016",
      "todate": "29/04/2016"
    }],
    "brand": "nokia"
  }],
  "rank": "1",
  "name": "first Mobile station"
}

{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "asdf976"
  },
  "Categories": [{
    "mainmodels": [{
      "submodels": [{
          "price": "2000",
          "submodelname": "lumia a02",

        }, {
          "price": "2000",
          "submodelname": "lumia trend",

        }

      ],
      "Status": "Active",
      "modelname": "lumia",
      "fromdate": "20/04/2016",
      "todate": "21/04/2016"
    }],
    "brand": "nokia"
  }],
  "rank": "2",
  "name": "Zahid station"
}
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "asdf976"
  },
  "Categories": [{
    "mainmodels": [{
      "submodels": [{
          "price": "2000",
          "submodelname": "trend 45",

        }, {
          "price": "2000",
          "submodelname": "trendz",

        }

      ],
      "Status": "Active",
      "modelname": "trend",
      "fromdate": "10/04/2016",
      "todate": "21/04/2016"
    }],
    "brand": "samsung"
  }],
  "rank": "3",
  "name": "mobi cell station"

}
```

Above i have added my data's which is stored in mongodb database . how can i find data only where ever 
 "Status": "Active",
 "modelname": "lumia",
 "date":"19/04/2016"

above is my condtion that date thing only i can't able to solve 
  here given date is between fromdate and todate then only it should give the result

i need to check given date (19/04/2016) which is between fromdate  and todate after that i need to check "Status": "Active",
 "modelname": "lumia",

my controller:

```
exports.search = function(req, res) {
 var condition = {
'modelname': 'lumia',
'Status':'Active'


};
        Phone.find(condition).sort('-created').populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function(err, phones) {
                if (err) {
                        return res.status(400).send({
                                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
                        });
                } else {
                        res.jsonp(phones);

                }
        });
};
```

schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var submodelSchema = {
   submodelname: {type:String, required: false},
   price: {type:String, required: false},
   Remainingphones: {type:String, required: false},
   Bookedphones: {type:String, required: false},
   Numofphones: {type:String, required: false}
 };

submodelSchema  = 'new Schema('+ submodeleSchema +',{_id:true})';

var typeSchema = {
   vtype: {type:String, required: false},
   mainservices: {
   Status: {type:String, required: false},
   modelname : {type:String, required: false},
   fromdate: {type: Date,default: Date.now},
   todate: {type: Date,default: Date.now}
   },
   submodels: [submodelSchema], default:[]
};
typeSchema  = 'new Schema('+typeSchema +',{_id:true})';

var PhoneSchema = new Schema({
        rank: {
                type: String,
                default: '',
                trim: true
        },
        name: {
                type: String,
                default: '',
                trim: true
        },
   Categories: [typeSchema], default:[]


});
 mongoose.model('Phone', PhoneSchema);
```

Comment: why you have stored fromdate and todate in string format? If you have stored that in timestamp or proper date string, then this will work: { 
 "Categories.mainmodels.Status" : "Active", 
 "Categories.mainmodels.modelname" : "lumia",
 "Categories.mainmodels.fromdate" : { "$lt" : new Date() },
 "Categories.mainmodels.todate" : { "$gt" : new Date() }
}

Comment: how can i store please help me out @Hiren

Comment: set date timestamp value in fromdate and todate.                    example:   new date().getTime()

Comment: can you please update my controller code for selection bw two dates with status and modelname @ Hiren

Comment: Have you updated  fromdate: {type: Date,default: Date.now},
   todate: {type: Date,default: Date.now} this ? or it was already exists? and

Comment: If it was already exists, then show me code for saving your document.

Comment: it was already exists . i have given my schema and database above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109551/discussion-between-hiren-s-and-komal).

Comment: @komal I couldn't able to understand your code, It seems so complex, You are using a complicated schema, You should avoid such type of nested more than one level deep structure for schema.

Comment: how can i get it done

Answer (score 4):

If you want to find your **query date** between `fromdate` and `todate` and also check `modelname` and `Status` then can follow this condition.

Aaccording to your given model structure you need to use **dot** (`.`) notation to check your date like: `Categories.mainmodels.fromdate` and need to use `$lte` (**less than or equal**) and `$gte` (**greater than or equal**) operator.

```
var queryDate = '19/04/2016';  // or like: var queryDate = req.query.date; or as you sent

 var condition = {
       'modelname': 'lumia',
       'Status':'Active',
       'Categories.mainmodels.fromdate': {$gte: queryDate },
       'Categories.mainmodels.todate': {$lte: queryDate }
};

Phone.find(condition).sort('-created').// rest of code
```

Comment: if i query like this i am getting empty

Comment: check by demo data that has in DB and date convert like `var queryDate = new Date('2016-04-19');`

Comment: and one thing I don't understand how store your date? If use `type:Date` then should save in db like this format '2015-07-06T07:59:39.221Z'

Comment: i given my schema pls check

Comment: i am getting empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110110/discussion-between-shaishab-roy-and-komal).

Answer (score 3):

I didn't understand your question properly but you should store your date as Date.
and you can design your schema something like this

```
    fromDate: Date,
    untilDate: Date
```

and to find if the date falls between the dates that are stored in fromDate and untilDate you can use **$gte** and **$lt**

```
 $gte: fromDate,
 $lte : untilDate
```

Comment: i need find query for between dates

Comment: i have made schema like that oly

Comment: statics.search =
  function ( from, until, callback) {   var conditions = {

      "fromDate": { $gte: from },
      "untilDate": { $lte: until }
    };

Comment: exports.search = function(req, res) {
 var condition = {
'modelname': 'lumia',
'Status':'Active'


};
        Phone.find(condition).sort('-created').populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function(err, phones) {
                if (err) {
                        return res.status(400).send({
                                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
                        });
                } else {
                        res.jsonp(phones);

                }
        });
};

Answer (score 1):

Just modify your condition variable to

```
var yourDate='19-04-2016';    
var condition = {
     'modelname':'lumia',
     'Status':'Active',
     'fromDate':{ $gte: yourDate},
     'untilDate':{$lte : yourDate}

};
```

You can go through this documentation about $gte and $lte

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/

Also if the date is not in the proper format or if type of date 
 is string you will have to explicitly parse it  using Moment.js.

Below is the Link have a look at it:
 http://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: if i send one date it should check and push the data for example i will send  15/04/2016 it shoud check with fromdate and todate

Comment: please check my question . i have sotred data like this

Comment: Just Try This

var condition = {
     'modelname':'lumia',
     'Status':'Active',
     'fromDate':{ $gte: yourDate},
     'untilDate':{$lte : yourDate}

};

Comment: no it's not working .it showing all data instead of showing matched data

Comment: Its showing empty because you need to convert type of the date from string to date using Moment.js

Check the Link

http://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: how can i do that hel me out

Comment: Go to that link everything has been specified first install npm moment.
Then just require the file
var moment = require('moment');
then use
moment().format(yourDate);

Comment: why i need to formate date i stored like this  "fromdate": "15/04/2016",    "todate": "29/04/2016" and i passed same formate

Comment: Try This

var yourDate='19-04-2016';    

var condition = {
     'modelname':'lumia',
     'Status':'Active',
     'fromDate':{ $gte: ISODate(yourDate)},
     'untilDate':{$lte : ISODate(yourDate)}

};
It is necessary because date format and string format are totally different .It creates a mismatch when you pass it as a string thus does not show any result.

Comment: i am getting empty oly

Answer (score 1):

Best way would be to save the date values as Date rather than String. While you are inserting the data, do => 'categories.mainmodels.fromdate':new Date('date-string') and same for the other date. This will create a Date type in db which will be easier to compare like below. Do follow the mm/dd/yyyy format to create new date;

var givenDate = new Date('04/19/2016');   (mm/dd/yyyy)

var condition = {
       'modelname': 'lumia',
       'Status':'Active',
       'Categories.mainmodels.fromdate': {$gte: givenDate },
       'Categories.mainmodels.todate': {$lte: givenDate }
};

Phone.find(condition).sort('-created').

Mind you, instead of just "date-string", while inserting/updating do new Date("date-string") which will create date and will allow you to compare like above.

If the value is date itself in db, remember to create the date from the string you want to compare with. In your case, where you have {$gte: 'date-string'} replace with {$gte: new Date('date-string')} and so for the other one. [This is to follow only if the data is already stored as date and it returns date value but not date string.